# Using List.of() for immutable list with single element instead of Collections.singletonList()

Tags: java, java-9

Java 9 introduced factory methods to create *immutable* lists with [`List.of()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/List.html#of-E-) method.

Which is more suitable to create an immutable list of one element?

- `List<String> immutableList1 = List.of("one");`
- `List<String> immutableList2 = Collections.singletonList("one");`

Comment: Im not sure about best practice `singletonList` will accept only one element . but Not `List.of` .

Comment: I mean what is it preferable when creating immutable list with single element. I prefer using `List.of`, but it's more suited to this use case in terms of performance?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Prefer using factory method

```
List<String> immutableList1 = List.of("one");
```

**Because** they disallow null elements is one of the benefit and also factory methods in `List` interface are handy to add multiple objects and creates immutable List

> They disallow null elements. Attempts to create them with null elements result in NullPointerException.

Where `Collections.singletonList` allows `null` value

```
List<String> l = Collections.singletonList(null);
System.out.println(l);   //[null]
```

Comment: Beware that even calling `contains(null)` is not supported on a list created via `List.of(...)`