# Set.of vs Collections.singleton

Tags: java, set, singleton, java-9

Since the immutable implementation of `Set.of(E e)` has been introduced in `Java 9`, do we still need to use `Collections.singleton(E e)`? What would be the use case for the latter one?

It doesn't seem to be obvious from looking at the source code of both implementations. I don't see any significant difference except that `Set12` implementation explicitly denies deserialisation.

I would personally go for `Set.of(...)` for the all new code at least because of the stylish point of view (a shorter code, less imports). But may be I am missing some crucial point?

Comment: Quite possibly unmodifiable vs immutable as explained in [this blog](http://marxsoftware.blogspot.com/2018/01/schopenhauers-law-immutability.html).

Comment: There is a similar kind of question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55418248/using-list-of-for-immutable-list-with-single-element-instead-of-collections-sing#comment97556151_55418248

Comment: @soorapadman Indeed, closed as duplicate :p

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The two methods behave almost the same. The only difference I can think of is that `Collections.singleton()` allows a `null` element, while `Set.of()` does not.

This will work:

```
Set<String> setofnull = Collections.singleton(null);
```

This won't (it will throw `NullPointerException`):

```
Set<String> setofnull = Set.of(null);
```

If the element you are putting in the `Set` cannot be `null`, I'd go with `Set.of()` too.

Comment: in my opinion, they should deprecate  `Collections.singleton()`. never is a good thing to have two methods of doing almost the same

Comment: Oh, that's a nice point about having possibility to put there a null value! Though I agree with a commentator that it is not something really needed